# jQuery.each not running in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where some form elements depend on another form input to have a certain value, or possibly multiple elements with specific values before that input is shown.

The idea is that when the form is generated, the wrapping div for each input has a data-depends-on attribute with a comma-separated list of each field that it depends on to be shown, and the values for each that it's expecting to be shown.

I almost have the front-end / JavaScript code down to do the lifting, but for some reason my jQuery.each() loop in a JavaScript function isn't running even though I've confirmed the array I'm trying to loop through a. has content, and b. that the functioning is actually being called when it is expected to do so.

First, I have the actual function call (which is called whenever a dependency input is changed):

```
checkShowField(keyed_depends, current_vals, targeted_element);
```

And then the function checkShowField() definition:

```
function checkShowField(keyed_dependencies, current_values, targeted_element)
{
    var hide_field = null;
    jQuery.each(keyed_dependencies, function(key, value)
    {
        if (value != current_values[key] && hide_field == null)
            hide_field = false;
    });

    if (hide_field == null)
        $(targeted_element).slideDown();
    else
        $(targeted_element).slideUp();
}
```

Also please note that the function call is placed in the proper place, and is actually being called. I just added the code on here to show everyone context of how the function is being called. The function call is wrapped in $(document).ready(function() {...}.

So as you can see, in the function "checkShowField", I have a jQuery.each loop that should be looping through keyed_dependencies array, but in actuality, the loop isn't even running once. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please define `keyed_depends`, `current_vals`, `targeted_element`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check, if `keyed_dependencies` in argument list has a property `length`. If so, jQuery assumes an array and might actually fail to run you loop.

If that is the case, try using vanilla JS:

```
for (var key in keyed_dependencies) {...}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As I believe that I said, keyed_dependencies does have content - I have double and triple checked this. It is an array with content.

Comment: Actually, I think that you might be on to something here. For some reason the length of keyed_dependencies is 0, even though it has one element in the array. Thoughts?

Comment: How do you define ``keyed_dependencies``? Do you instantiate a `class` (so you have inherited properties only) or are you using a plain array-object?

Comment: It's a plain array object. keyed_depends = []; is instantiated and then elements are added with associative keys, which is passed to checkShowField().

Also, when I use a regular for loop, like you suggested, it works...can you explain to me what's causing this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could that be the problem? jQuery assumes an array (because ``keyed_dependencies`` has the property ``length``, as all arrays do. BUT: You are using non-numerical keys.  ``jQuery.each`` uses numeric keys to run the loop, if you pass it an actual array. So you loop will fail.

Comment: ... or use {} to initialize ``keyed_dependencies``

Comment: That would make sense then. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keyed_dependencies is not really what you think it is.  Try adding `debugger;` statements before the `.each` line and maybe in the function as well.  Then use inspector/debugger to review the data in the variables.

Comment: Unfortunately...it is. I have done this, and it is an array as expected, which is why I can't figure it out. Has to be something I'm overlooking.

http://prntscr.com/98eti5

Comment: Could it be confusion in jQuery from the two different types of `each()` it has?  If it's really an array why not use the native `forEach()`?